# Python pandas .isnull() does not work on NaT in object dtype

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, isnull

I have this series:

```
ser=pd.Series([11,22,33,np.nan,np.datetime64('nat')],name='my_series')
```

The series looks like this:

```
0     11
1     22
2     33
3    NaN
4    NaN
Name: my_series, dtype: object
```

But I get only one `True` for NULL values:

```
ser.isnull()

0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: my_series, dtype: bool
```

Is it a bug or how can I count correctly the NULL values in a pandas series? This does not help:

```
ser=ser.replace('NaN',np.nan)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you creating the series, in your actual code as well?

Comment: does `ser.loc[4]` result in `NaN` or `NaT`? I think that datetime64 can deal interchangeably with NaN and NaT, but attributing a NaT to a series of  'object' causes the problem

Comment: Yes. Of course this is only an example... The second `NaN` has been converted from `NaT` (??) but there can be some trouble during conversion. Or maybe there is no conversion:`ser.loc[4]` results `NaT`

Comment: what is your pandas version? Do you get same issue if you use `pd.NaT` instead of `np.datetime64('nat')` ?

Comment: Oh, `.isnull()` works perfectly with `pd.NaT`. Thanks!!! pandas version is 0.16.2, numpy version is 1.9.2

Comment: should prob work, issue created [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11206)

Comment: This looks to be due to an outdated version of pandas or numpy. Works fine for me (pd 0.23.4, np 1.15.4) `np.isnat(np.datetime64('nat')) == True`, `pd.isnull(np.datetime64('nat')) == True`

Answer (score 6):

I ran into a similar issue this morning but in an str series! This worked for me and with your sample data as well:

`pd.isna(ser)`

Answer (score 0):

To get around this, you can also do

`series.apply(lambda x: str(x) == "nat")`

Then you can still use np.datetime if you want

Comment: This does not work. `series.apply(lambda x: str(x) == "NaT")` **does** work.  Beware case sensitivity in string comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly I got following output after execution the code you given:
[image]

#### Alternate way is: count those values which you are able to count.

calculate length of series object and subtraction will give you the count for null values. As follows:**

[image]

```
len(ser)-(ser[ser.isnull()==False]).count()
```